# What does the word 「しとったんや」 mean?

Tags: words, dialects

Here is the sentence including the word.

だいたいだな　ジョーってやつはじぶんの腹{はら}をこやすために　うちのせがれどもを利{り}用{よう}**しとったんや**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

しとったんや means しておったのだ → していたのだ, "was doing", in colloquial Kansai-ben.