# What しとっても means here?

Tags: colloquial-language, dialects, contractions, subsidiary-verbs

> 陸ではのらくらしとっても水の中ではそりゃあ素早い

I don't quite understand しとっても form here.

I guess the whole sentence will be

> Even though they're slow on land, they're very quick in water.

Is しとっても another form of していても or しておいても?

Comment: It might be dialect: https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1389225183

Comment: Related (or possible duplicate?): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25267/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61180/9831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

のらくらしとっても is a contraction of のらくらしておっても, which is a dialectal version of のらくらしていても.

- In casual speech, [て + おる contracts to とる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18157/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8F-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8F-for-preparation-conjugation-and-nuance/18159#18159).
- This おる is the same as progressive-いる, but used mainly in western Japan. See: [おる in honorific contexts](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26091/5010)